# Can I add a css class style to a dynamically fetched JSON string?

Tags: html, css, json, flutter, dart

I have a string that is coming dynamically from JSON:

```
{"line 1":"<p>Hello<\/p>\n<p>I am an example<\/p>\n<p>Hello 2<\/p>\n"}
```

**Problem:**

When I output this to Dart / Flutter, using this: `? Text(widget.place!.line1 ?? ""`

I get three lines, plain text. This does not allow me to style them separately in Dart.

My question: can I assign classes to the lines or keep their HTML formatting in a way for me to do some kind of CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flutter_html` package as follow:

1. add the below code to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter_html: ^2.1.2
```

2. run `flutter pub get`
3. use this widget according to this [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html/example).

Comment: I don't see it. How does this add a class to a DYNAMIC JSON string?